# Can the question author "accept" a close vote?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I just solved a user's [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50543686/1115360) in VB.NET by getting them to use [Option Strict On](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273139/232762) so that the correct overload of XmlDocument.Load was picked by the compiler.

I would like to say to the user that I could vote to close with a reason of "Problem can no longer be reproduced."

Can *the user* then accept the close vote so that the question is immediately closed? If so, how would they do that?

Is there any detriment to the user's status for having a question closed? If so, I would concoct an answer instead.

**The conclusion:** I wrote an answer, and added some useful information from other users.

Comment: Only for suggested duplicates, I think - a banner appears for them.

Comment: No, a user can't *accept* a non-duplicate close vote. Those type of close votes require 5 voters. A closed question can contribute to a question ban.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah, I think I've seen suggested duplicates accepted by the community user - would that be when the OP accepts the dupe suggestion?

Comment: @rene If that is definitive, I will accept it if it is posed as an answer.

Comment: are you sure it's no repo? wouldn't this be a problem other users may have from time to time?

Comment: @YvetteColomb The proper way to use VB.NET is to use Option Strict On so that the compiler doesn't make sub-optimal choices. No-one who does would reproduce the problem. The OP seems like a nice person and I wouldn't want their reputation tarnished by a decision by Microsoft to have Option Strict Off as the default in Visual Studio.

Comment: @AndrewMorton In my opinion, since the fact is that option strict is by default off, I'd suggest the question shouldn't be closed. (personally, the proper way to use VB.NET is to migrate all the code to C# but sadly that's not always an option. :) )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, the author can only accept closure as a duplicate. They cannot single-handedly close their question for other reasons, whether there are close votes on it or not.

They can:

- flag it for closure, which will get it to the Close Votes review queue with the stated reason
- cast a close vote themselves if they have the privilege
- delete it, [subject to limitations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: Rather than single-handledly, I was proposing to VTC so that the OP could accept that vote whereupon the question would be closed and the OP would suffer no detriment to their reputation. So I am asking about the situation where there is collaboration.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The OP wouldn't suffer a detriment to their reputation in any case. Closing makes it impossible to post answers, and the automatic deletion criteria are more strict, that's all.

Comment: Rene noted in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368669/can-user-accept-close-vote/368672#comment595108_368669) earlier that "A closed question can contribute to a question ban."

Comment: @AndrewMorton You need to have a really consistent record of bad questions to get a ban. They have nothing to worry about unless they plan to make a habit of it. After all, they wasted everyone's time on a badly written question (didn't bother to debug the code themselves first, localize the error and make an MCVE, for starters) -- it's only natural that it prompts them to do better next time.

Comment: @AndrewMorton that said, an answer "VB may pick a wrong overload without option strict on" is the correct answer here, so the question is not so close-worthy. There's already a similar one -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754684/vb-net-functon-overload-confusion -- but it's without an answer.

Comment: I think that with a better title it would be a more useful question. I have not yet thought of that title, hang on... I might have something.